# Getting input value to action method. Mvc Core & AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm new to MVC Core and i'm having some struggles getting this right.

I've got a table filled with some basic values from my products, and what i want is to send a quantity value and an id of the product to my action method. The problem i'm having is that i'm able to send my product.ID to the action method, but i can't seem to get my input value. I tried using a button instead of my  element and when i used that i managed to get the input but not the product.ID.

```
@model List<Product>

<div id="productList">
    <form>
        <table>
            @foreach (var product in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@product.Name</td>
                    <td>@product.Price</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <a
                           asp-action="AddProductToCart"
                           asp-route-id="@product.ID"
                           data-ajax="true"
                           data-ajax-method="GET"
                           data-ajax-mode="replace"
                           data-ajax-update="#cartinfo">Add to basket</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="cartinfo">

</div>
```

My action methods parameters looks like this:

```
public IActionResult AddProductToCart(int id, int quantity)
```

I'm sure i'm missing some basic knowledge about how forms work so i'd really appreciate getting some help here. I've been trying to google this but i'm struggling with that as well. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man, now i know what developers mean when they say that their code from 1 year ago is trash. Not sure if i should feel embarrassed or proud, haha.

My solution now would've probably been to post using JS. Also i wouldn't have placed my "asp-route-id="@product.ID" on an  element, i could've just put it as a hidden input and posted it. Oh and that data-ajax-mode stuff confused me more than it helped, remove that for sure.

Note to self: **Keep improving. :-)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript instead.

```
@model List<Product>

<div id="productList">
    <form>
        <table>
            @foreach (var product in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                   <td style="visibility:hidden" class="pID">@product.ID</td>
                    <td>@product.Name</td>
                    <td>@product.Price</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="quantity" class="qty"/></td>
                    <td>

                     <button class="btnAdd" >Add to basket</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="cartinfo">

</div>
```

java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.btnAdd').click(function () {
            var PID= $(this).closest("tr").find(".pID").text();
            var Pqty= $(this).closest("tr").find(".qty").text();

            AddtoCart(PID, Pqty);
        });

    }); 

    function AddtoCart(pid,qty) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("AddProductToCart", "Your Controller")",
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: pid, quantity: qty},
                datatype: 'json',

                success: function (data) {

                    $('#cartinfo').html(data);

                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer Anoos! I know quite a bit more about JS but i'm taking an ASP.NET Core MVC course right now so i'm trying not to use JS to save me haha. Do you know how i could use tag helpers or any other sort of way to send the values to the action method? I really appreciate your comment, glad to know at least one way to do this now :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put **data-ajax** attribute in the `<form>` ,and make the following changes in your view and the parameter in the action

```
<div id="productList">
    <table>
        @foreach (var product in Model)
        {
            <tr>
              <form data-ajax="true"
                       data-ajax-url="/Your controllerName/AddProductToCart"
                       data-ajax-method="Post"
                       data-ajax-mode="replace"
                       data-ajax-update="#cartinfo">
               <td>@product.Name</td>
                <td>@product.Price</td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text"  asp-for="@product.quantity"/>
                    <input asp-for="@product.Id" hidden />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to basket"/>
                </td>
             </form>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Change the parameters to Model object , note that the parameter name must be consistent with the name of the data passed from the client side

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddProductToCart( Product product)
    {
        //the stuff you want
    }
```

Comment: I thought about doing that but that would mean that i'd have to put a property on my Product class named Quantity, which feels like a work-around. But if that's the "correct" way to do this then i'll do it for sure. Thanks a lot